# Как организовать подстановку всех индексов массива?

Tags: php

Весь код: https://pastebin.com/5c317zU8

Имеется php код. Который уже работает нужно только организовать подстановку по порядку от начала и до конца индексов массива.

```
list($a1, $b1, $c1, $d1, $e1, $f1, $g1, $h1, $i1, $j1, $k1, $l1, $m1, $n1, $o1, $p1, $q1, $r1, $s1, $t1, $u1, $v1, $w1, $x1, $y1, $z1) = explode(', ', trim($file1[0], ', '));
```

Пытался это сделать с помощью функции key(). Прописав так trim($file1[$key], ', ')

Что в результате приводит к ошибке / Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Понимаю что это значит что я пытаюсь передать массив вместо строки. Но как сделать так, что бы подставлять индекс массива как строку от начала и до конца индексов массива по порядку. Скорее всего это делается через функцию foreach но не знаю как.

Сам результат выполнения php скрипта: https://pastebin.com/yPBXzgCd

А должно быть так: https://pastebin.com/htGNCrFq

Updated:

Исправленный код: https://pastebin.com/yJhMckLr

То что получается: https://pastebin.com/KJ73WNSM

А должно быть так: https://pastebin.com/htGNCrFq

Пока что так и не могу понять как организовывать обработку индексов от начала и до конца. По типу от 0 до n-ого числа индекса. То есть, от начала и до конца 
индексов массива.

Comment: Функция trim() работает со строками. Ошибка говорит, что $file1[0] не строка, а массив. Сделайте var_dump($file1[0]) что бы понимать, что Вы передаете

Comment: результат выполнения var_dump($file[0]) / string(138) "4high_bkn, bkn_wi3, 100, 12582912, 0, -41.469, -40.7371, -11.0741, 5.86037, 0.659833, 13.514, -17.8043, -20.0386, 1.21992, 33.7578, null " Выше я уже писал что выдает ошибку когда пытаюсь поставить key как переменную за место индекса.

Comment: А в коде у Вас написано $file1[0], $file2[0]

Comment: Просто оставил рабочий вариант. Не рабочий вариант который приводит к ошибке list($a1, $b1, $c1, $d1, $e1, $f1, $g1, $h1, $i1, $j1, $k1, $l1, $m1, $n1, $o1, $p1, $q1, $r1, $s1, $t1, $u1, $v1, $w1, $x1, $y1, $z1) = explode(', ', trim($file1[$key], ', ')); Попытка подставить индексы массива.

Comment: Исправил код теперь с key тоже работает, но не так как мне надо: https://pastebin.com/yJhMckLr Получается: https://pastebin.com/KJ73WNSM И это не то что мне нужно. Сам файл который пытаюсь преобразовать в json: https://pastebin.com/8vGSSxa6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

настойчивость и желание во чтобы то ни стало добиться цели это хорошее качество, но не надо ради этого писать 26 переменных (:

Я так понимаю, что ваша задача - разбить входную строку по разделителю. Вас интересует, допустим первые 26 значений, поскольку именно столько переменных вы берете. Хотя при этом используете только до `o` (15). Надеюсь, вы знали что можно не перечислять все переменные, какие придут из `explode`, а ограничится нужными 15ю.

Но суть не в этом. Вы разбили строку на 26 переменных, и теперь хотите вписать их на нужные места в некий JSON, вставляя их туда вручную.

Предлагаю вам пойти другим путем. Вот к примеру тестовая строка и нумерация элементов в ней (для проверки результата).

```
//      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
$src = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
$input = explode(',', $src);
```

Задайте схему, т.е. структуру формируемого json, где вместо значений будут индексы получаемых элементов:

```
$schema = [
        "aabbMin"  => [6,7,8],
        "aabbMax"  => [9,10,11],
        "centroid" => [12,13,14],
        "radius" =>  15,
        "archetypeName" => 1,
        "txdName" => 2,
];
```

А теперь рекурсивно обойдя все элементы замените индексы на полученные значения:

```
$data = $schema;
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$v) use ($input){
           $v = $input[$v-1];
      });
```

результат выполнения

```
Array   (
    [aabbMin] => Array (
            [0] => F
            [1] => G
            [2] => H
        )
    [aabbMax] => Array (
            [0] => I
            [1] => J
            [2] => K
        )
    [centroid] => Array (
            [0] => L
            [1] => M
            [2] => N
        )
    [radius] => O
    [archetypeName] => A
    [txdName] => B
)
```

Если такую операцию надо провести для всех строк входного файла, то все это дело успешно оборачивается в цикл:

```
 $lines = file("input.txt");
 $schema = ...;
 $result = [];
 foreach($lines as $l){
    $input = explode(...);
    $data = $schema;
    array_walk_recursive(....);
    $result[] = $data;
 }
 echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы прочитали первую строку файла, представляющую из себя некоторые значения разделённые запятой, откинули запятые и пробелы по краям этой строки и разделили её, получив те самые значения.

И теперь вы хотите проделать тоже самое с каждой строкой файла? В PHP для этого предусмотрена конструкция `foreach`:

```
foreach ($file as $line) {
    $vals = explode(', ', trim($line, ', '));
    // ...
}
```

Как видите переменная `$key` не требуется.

Прочитал ваше дополнение и хочу обратить внимание, что в цикле же надо и формировать вашу структуру. Иначе переменные просто перезаписываются и вы получаете результат только последней строки.

Обратите внимание, что JSON можно сформировать с помощью функции `json_encode`:

```
$t = [];
foreach ($file1 as $line) {
    $vals = explode(', ', trim($line, ', '));
    $t[] = [
        'aabbMin' => array_map('floatval', [$vals[5], $vals[6], $vals[7]]),
        'aabbMax' => array_map('floatval', [$vals[8], $vals[9], $vals[10]]),
        'centroid' => array_map('floatval', [$vals[11], $vals[12], $vals[13]]),
        'radius' => floatval($vals[14]),
        'archetypeName' => $vals[0],
        'txdName' => $vals[1],
    ];
}

$json = json_encode($t);
echo $t;
```

Comment: А как сформировать подобную структуру? https://pp.userapi.com/c845420/v845420466/1e24f/TXrjQ0TsxEM.jpg
В данный момент структура в виде сплошной строки. И я боюсь что могут возникнуть проблемы и за того что все сплошной строкой. Когда эти данные будут обрабатываться. То есть организовать структуру для каждой строки. А не записывать сплошной строкой. Просто интересно как это решить.

Comment: @WilpsScrag `json_encode($t,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`. Но это имеет смысл только если JSON предназначен для чтения человеком. Для программы одна строка не представляет проблем.